# Formatting issue with template function in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to use some of my scope attributes in a template function inside of my custom directive. I cannot seem to get the formatting working for the return piece in my template.  Here is what it looks like.  I am guessing that I will need

```
    angular
        .module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
        .directive('jiText', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                scope: {
                    label: '@',
                    name: '@',
                    value: '@',
                    placeholder: '@',
                    tooltips: '@',
                    maxLength: '@',
                    width: '@'
                },
                template: function (element, attrs) {
                    return '<div dx-text-box="{'+ attrs.id + attrs.placeholder + attrs.value + attrs.maxLength + '}"></div>';
                }
                //templateUrl: 'FormTest/views/ji-Text.html'
            }
        });
```

The line that is not formatted correctly is:

```
return '<div dx-text-box="{'+ attrs.id + attrs.placeholder + attrs.value + attrs.maxLength + '}"></div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have those variables defined on your scope, you should use the scope instead of attrs. Assuming that you just want to concatenate all those parameters, the template should then be:

```
template: '<div dx-text-box="{{ id + placeholder + value + maxLength }}"></div>';
```

You'd also need to add `id: '@'` to your scope.

Comment: Thanks Anid! question, For some reason I am not able to see anything during run time such as the placeholder value.  Do I have to use a link or compile function to get this to work?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped my original answer. You should just able able to refer to the variables as shown above.

Comment: Thanks again.  I actually had to do it using the attribute in stead of scope. But your formatting helped for sure.  Here is how I have it if your interested.                template: function (element, attrs) {
                    return '<div dx-text-box="{ placeholder: \''+ attrs.placeholder + '\' }"></div>'
                }